# Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation and that $C = X/R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, equivalence-relations

Consider a non empty set $C$ with non empty elements such that, for all $x$ and $y$ belonging to $C$ , if $x \neq y$ then  $x \cap y = \emptyset$.

Let $X = \bigcup C$ and define a relation $R$ as the set of pairs $(x, y) \in X^2$ that for such exist $z \in C$ s.t. $x \in z$ and $y \in z$.

$(i)$ Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $X$

$(ii)$ Show that $C = X/R$

I have no idea how to approach this exercise.

Comment: The collection $C$ is called a partition. You can think of the sets $x$ and $y$ as bins that contain everything that is equal. A simple example might be sorting by color when we put two things in the same bin if they are the same color.

You need to show that this works the other way, where you start with the bins and then claim everything in the bin is equal to everything else in the bin. Do this by verifying the axioms of an equivalence relation work when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, your statement of the problem is somewhat unclear. I guess you are saying $C$ is a non-empty set of non-empty sets, and $C$ has the property that any two distinct sets in $C$ are disjoint.

Your definition of $X$ is very unclear. However, I believe you mean to say $X = \bigcup_{x\in C} x $.

If this is what you mean to say, then we can proceed.

(i) To prove $R$ is an equivalence relation, you must show reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity.
Reflexivity and symmetry are immediate (if you need further explanation, comment so). For transitivity, let $x,y,u \in X$ be so that $(x,y), (y,u)\in R$. We wish to show $(x,u)\in R$.
By definition of $R$, there is $z_1,z_2 \in C$ such that $x,y\in z_1$ and $y,u \in z_2$. By the property of $C$, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are either disjoint or equal. Since $y\in z_1 \cap z_2$, we have the latter case. Therefore $z_1 = z_2$ and therefore $x,u\in z_1$. Hence $(x,u) \in R$.
This proves (i).

(ii) For this part, we just show set containment. Let $z \in C$. Since $z$ is not empty, there is $x \in z \subset X$. I claim $z = [x]$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x\in X$ with respect to $R$. This is another set equivalence argument. Let $y\in z$. Then since $x\in z$ as well, we have $(x,y)\in R$ and hence $y\in [x]$. Let $y\in [x]$. Then there is $z_1\in C$ so that $x,y\in z_1$. However, by the property of $C$, $z = z_1$, and hence $y\in z$. Thus $z = [x] \in X/R$. This shows $C \subset X/R$.

On the other hand, let $[x]\in X/R$. By definition of $X$, $x\in z$ for some $z\in C$. Use a similar argument as above to show $[x] = z$. Once you show this, then you have $[x] \in C$, and hence $X/R \subset C$. Thus giving $C = X/R$.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on why symmetry and reflexivity are immediate?

Comment: For reflexivity, let $x$\in $X$. By construction of $x$ there is $z\in C$ so that $x \in z$. So, we have a $z \in C$ so that $x \in z$ and $x\in z$. Therefore $(x,x)\in R$. @Arthurios

Comment: For symmetry, let $x,y\in X$. If $(x,y)\in R$, then there is $z\in C$ so that $x\in z $ and $y\in z$. This is the same as saying $y \in z$ and $x \in z$. Therefore there is some $z\in C$ so that $y \in z$ and $x \in z$. So $(y,x)\in R$. @Arthurios